# Is a CComPtr assignment threadsafe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, com

If you assign some globally or statically available COM pointer to a `CComPtr` within a thread, will that assignment be threadsafe?

I've located the following ATL source code (in light of the comment at the top, I'm not sure if it's still used, but I can't find what the new code might be):

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// No Longer Used Smart Pointer helpers, retained for source compatibility
ATLINLINE ATLAPI_(IUnknown*) AtlComPtrAssign(
    _Inout_opt_ _Deref_pre_maybenull_ _Deref_post_maybenull_ IUnknown** pp,
    _In_opt_ IUnknown* lp)
{
    if (pp == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if (lp != NULL)
        lp->AddRef();
    if (*pp)
        (*pp)->Release();
    *pp = lp;
    return lp;
}
```

Is it possible that after successfully checking `if (lp != NULL)`, the `lp` object could be released and destroyed from a different thread, thereby leading to a crash when `lp->AddRef()` is called?

And if so, is there a way to protect the assignment with a mutex?

Comment: [Is ATL's CComPtr not thread safe ?!!](http://computer-programming-forum.com/77-vc-atl/56b7828459e9d05b.htm)

Comment: `lp` is a local variable so can't change no matter what happens on another thread (assuming no undefined behaviour)

Comment: @RomanR. Yes, I saw that, but was hoping to find a more authoritative and up-to-date answer, as well as a potential solution.

Comment: The solution is rather straightforward: you should take responsibility for thread safety yourself and guard access to the variable with a mutex, critical section, SRW lock or alike.

Comment: AtlComPtrAssign is obsolete. If you want to share a CComPtr between threads, you could have problems, but just pass COM interface pointers between threads (with proper marshaling RoGetAgileReference , etc.). AddRef & Release are thread safe for object marked as free/both. I almost never use CComPtr as arguments to functions. So answer is no but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @SimonMourier So an STA pointer assignment would require a mutex?

Comment: You really should not be sharing COM pointers between threads.  They should be marshalled in to a new COM pointer for each thread.  Each thread would then have it's own smart pointer.

Comment: @RichardCritten I intend to do that, but if I understand correctly, even if you marshal, you wind up with an `IAgileReference` interface that needs to be shared.  So that's what I'm concerned about accessing in a thread-safe manner.

Comment: No you should end up with a new raw com pointer that can only be used on the new thread.  Then you wrap it with a smart pointer. See `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream` _"Marshals an interface pointer from one thread to another thread in the same process."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-comarshalinterthreadinterfaceinstream

Comment: Answering your question specifically: the caller of `AtlComPtrAssign` presumably holds a reference on the interface that `lp` points to (or else it passed a dangling pointer to the function to begin with, and all bets are off). So the object can't be destroyed mid-way through (barring bugs elsewhere). Once the function returns, the caller is free to release its reference, but `*pp` still holds one.

Comment: Note "STA object" or "STA pointer" are misnomers. Some objects (declare that they) can only be accessed by one thread ("fixed-thread" object is more correct than STA object). COM ensures this when you use CoCreateInstance and declared COM methods (with proxy/stub). But you must also not pass/copy raw COM pointers from thread to thread, as COM can't do anything in this case. And the best is to keep smart pointers in a given thread (or even in a given method). That's all you have to worry, and you should not have any problem.

Comment: @SimonMourier But what about passing the `IAgileReference` pointer?  At some point you have to do that, right?

Comment: Exactly, this one is the joker: *The agile reference can be passed to another apartment within the same process, where the original object is retrieved by using the IAgileReference interface* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-rogetagilereference#remarks